# Como detectar el valor de un span angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Tengo un dropdown con un par de opciones, quiero escuchar cuando el valor del span que tiene la opción seleccionada cambia a otra opción, es decir si la opción es A y se cambia a B, quiero escuchar ese cambio, estoy usando Angular

```
      <div class="options" #opt id="optItem" >
        <span title="Idioma" class="dropdown-toggle selected-item"> A </span> //Listen this  change
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>opt A</li>
          <li>opt B</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR? Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás trabajando con una lista y no con un `<select>` te recomendaria que usaras la acción click de Angular para capturar el evento y luego realizar la acción que necesites.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li (click)="doAction('A')">opt A</li>
   <li (click)="doAction('B')">opt B</li>
</ul>
```